# Slerp formula interpretation

Tags: quaternions

I have a problem about [spherical linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp#Quaternion_Slerp), or *slerp* for short.

As linked, Wikipedia gives the following formula for an interpolation between quaternions `q0` and `q1` with a `t` parameter (between 0 and 1):

[image: Quaternion formula]

My misunderstanding here is about the `t` exponent. Before this formula, the same page displays:

> qt = cos*tΩ* + v * sin*tΩ*

But I'm not sure this is the formula to take to complete this one, nor how to find this `Ω` angle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $|q_0|=|q_1|$, the quotient $q_1q_0^{-1}$ is a unit quaternion. Thus, it has a polar form $$ q_1q_0^{-1}=\exp(\Omega\mathbf{v})=\cos\Omega+\sin\Omega\,\mathbf{v} $$

where $\Omega\in[0,\pi)$ (assuming $q_1\ne\pm q_0$ so $\Omega\ne\pi$) is a convex angle and $\mathbf{v}$ is a unit vector (hence also a square root of $-1$, which is why Euler's formula applies). From there you can define

$$ (q_1q_0^{-1})^t=\exp(t\Omega\mathbf{v})=\cos(t\Omega)+\sin(t\Omega)\mathbf{v} $$

for $0\le t\le1$.